# Dynamically create directories and files based on some value as part of there name

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to write a Python script that creates a directory and saves some images into that directory. Please check the below piece of code,

```
person = 0 # Increase this by one every iteration
if os.path.isdir('./training__data/s{str(person)}') is False: # if, for ex. s0 does not exist
    os.mkdir('./training__data/s' + str(person)) # create s0, for ex.

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        samples += 1
        person += 1
        cv2.imwrite("training__data/s{str(person)}" + str(samples) + ".png", \
            gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])
```

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to create a file tree described below,

```
-- training__data/
    -- s0
       -- 0.png
       -- 1.png
       -- n.png   # goes until the nth picture
    -- s1
       -- 0.png
       -- 1.png
       -- n.png
    -- .          # goes until the nth directory
```

So my question is how can I name the directories as s0, s1, s2, etc.?

I tried adding this --> `s{str(person)}` which did not resolve the issue.

Thanks for your help in advance,
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate your string for the file and directory name, you may use [**`str.format`**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function. For example:

```
>>> "Hello {} {}".format("World", 2018)
'Hello World 2018'
```

Also, it is better to use [**`os.makedirs`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) in your case, because it creates the directory recursively, without checking for it whether path to it exists or not. *(But be careful to give the correct path)* (Note: with this an `OSError` is raised if the target directory already exists.)

Now you need to use nested `for` loops for your case. Outer loop for your directory generation, and inner loop for your file generation. Here's the sample code:

```
base_path = '/path/to/dir'

for i in range(10):
    dir_path = '{}/s{}'.format(base_path, i)
    os.makedirs(dir_path)
    for j in range(10):
        file_path = '{}/s{}.png'.format(dir_path, j)
        # your logic with file
```

Modify the above sample code with your logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python3, you need to use the format() function.

```
for i in range(5):
    print("somefile_{suffix}.txt".format(suffix=i))
    print("another_{0}_example{1}.lol".format(i*i, i/2))
```